# Why my derivative is not equal to theorical value?

Tags: python, numpy, derivative

I make a derivative computation on sinusoidale signal.
I make simple python program to test it:

```
signal = np.sin(time_s.to_numpy())
for index in range(1, len(signal)-1):
        first[index] = signal[index ]-signal[index -1] /(2*dt) * 100
        second[index] = signal[index+1 ] - 2*signal[index ]+signal[index -1] /(dt*dt)
        signal_display[index] = signal[index ]* 2000
```

[image]

My first derivative function should like a cosinus?

Comment: Your discretized derivatives aren't calculated properly. The first derivative is `(f(x + dt) - f(x)) / dt` but you're only dividing the second term by `dt`. Same for your second derivative. Also, since you're using `numpy` you should be using vectorized operations, not looping. See Ivan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses in the numerator of your derivatives, and you are scaling them inappropriately. They should look like this:

```
first[index] = (gyroX_filtered[index] - gyroX_filtered[index - 1]) / dt 
second[index] = (gyroX_filtered[index + 1] - 2 * gyroX_filtered[index] + gyroX_filtered[index - 1]) / dt**2
```

Answer (score 3):

Given a time series and signal:

```
>>> time_s = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000)
>>> signal = np.cos(time_s)
```

Now, the derivate is given by `f'(x) = (f(x + dt) - f(x)) / dt`. Where `dt` is the timestep:

```
>>> dt = time_s[1] - time_s[0]
0.015
```

You can use `np.roll` to compute it:

```
>>> d1 = (np.roll(signal, -1) - signal) / dt
```

or by using slicing with `(signal[1:] - signal[:-1]) / dt`.

You can plot both (`sin' = cos`):

```
>>> plt.plot(time_s, signal)
>>> plt.plot(time_s[:-1], d1[:-1])
```

[image]

Similarly you can do this with the 2nd order derivative given by `f''(x) = (f(x + dt) - 2f(x) + f(x - dt)) / dt²`:

```
>>> d2 = (np.roll(signal, -1) - 2*signal + np.roll(signal, 1)) / dt**2
```

Here the plot (`sin'' = -sin`):

```
>>> plt.plot(time_s, signal)
>>> plt.plot(time_s[1:-2], d2[1:-2])
```

[image]

Comment: It's a shame this wasn't accepted as it's a better answer.

Comment: @blorgon Surely OP wanted to find what was wrong with his/her code. This answer doesn't provide that but gives instead an alternative, *indeed more 'NumPythonic'*,  implementation. Sometimes the objective of some people is to get the job done as fast as possible without stepping back and learning alternative ways. Regardless of the answer that gets accepted, I hope OP did read learn something from this one!

Comment: @blorgon. Indeed my question was not how to compute a derivative but why with my program, I get the wrong shape. The fact, that the derivative was made with the previous or the next sample is not a wrong way to do derivative and it wont generate bad shape.  It is the same with the (dt*2) , this will just generate a wrong derivate size. Again in my case, my question was about the shape of my derivative  not how to make a derivative function.

Comment: @bird12358 your derivative calculations were *mathematically* incorrect, this is an objective fact. There is no such thing as a correct derivative with "wrong derivate size". That is mathematically nonsense.